# mod_rewrite within subfolder not working

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm currently getting to grips with mod_rewrite and have ran into a stumbling block which i was hoping someone would be kind enough to help

I have a site that is structured as so

https://www.abc.com/region1/
https://www.abc.com/region2/
https://www.abc.com/region3/

Within each of these folders lies two files i'll call example1.php and example2.php, both are dynamic

Regarding example1.php a possibility might be example1.php?var1=1
Regarding example2.php one possibility might be example2.php?var1=1&var2=1

I've been trying to use the following but its throwing a server 500 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example1alias/ example1alias/([^/\.]+)/?$ example1.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^example1alias/ example1alias/?$ example1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^example2alias/ example2alias/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ example2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

My .htaccess containing this code is located in the subfolder itself and if i understand mod_rewrite correctly the ^ tells the rule to run from the active path

Could someone point out what i'm doing incorrectly

As always any advise is greatly appreciated

Regards
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times HTTP 500 (for htaccess) are for syntax errors in the htaccess file.

For rewrite rules I believe the syntax is: RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

You seem to have more than one patterns for one rule, maybe you can try separating them out into 2 different rules.

- RewriteRule ^example2alias/ example2.php [L]
- RewriteRule ^example2alias/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ example2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]

Also add "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" to your htaccess file

Comment: Many thanks,i've reconfigured the htaccess and it appears to bw working now except for some issues with accessing my css and js files using relative paths,but i'm sure i can rectify that